# Stuttering on script during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a this script http://jsfiddle.net/evzb28jf/2/ but it stutters during the first part of animation. I suspect that it's because it's loading the entire site behind it. Is there a way to load in chunks or something? The splash page lasts for about 3.5secs.

```
<div id="splash">
<div class="square">Darrien Tu . <span class="l1"></span>
 <span class="l2"></span>
 <span class="l3"></span>
 <span class="l4"></span>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try firing the start if the animation after a 500ms delay. It's a hack, but may give your assets time to load. Or for that matter but a 5s delay on it and see if it still occurs. The issue may be unrelated to render other assets. If it does go away after everything else has loaded just fire a callback for the animation to kick off. You could look into promises but that would be over kill for something like this.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 Hmmm putting a 1.5s delay seemed to make it less choppy. How do I a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't give a complete answer because I don't know how your script is loading.

If you're using `$(function(){ ... })`, `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`, or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){})` to load your scripts, you could try `$(window).load(function(){ ... })` or `window.onload` (for native) as an alternative.

If your're still having the issue, you could wrap it in a short `setTimeout()`, for instance, 1 second after the page has loaded.

```
TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;

//show the square only once js has run
//visibility set to hidden in css panel
TweenLite.set(".square", {
    visibility: "visible"
});

var tl = new TimelineLite();

setTimeout(function(){
  tl.fromTo(".l1", 2, {
      height: 0
  }, {
      height: 102
  })
  .fromTo(".l2", 5, {
    width: 0,

  }, {
    width: 312

  })
  .fromTo(".l3", 2, {
    height: 0
  }, {
    height: 102
  })
  .fromTo(".l4", 5, {
    width: 0
  }, {
    width: 312
  })

  tl.timeScale(4) //play faster
}, 1000)
```

Also keep in mind that this really depends on the client.  Some clients are better than others, and you're also using JavaScript to animate which in some scenarios (also depending on the library) really isn't the best idea.